# Are card games included in the scope of Puzzling?

Tags: discussion

It is on topic to discuss card games such as Solitaire? A lot of card games are very similar to puzzles so it seems like they should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solitaires, definitely. Most multi-player games, however, are likely to be more about interpersonal strategy rather than puzzling per se, and should probably be sent to [Board and Card Games SE](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).